# Explain select output on a complex query that I didn't write

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I'm working on a codebase I didn't write and we're getting very bad performance on our SQL queries, so I thought we're probably missing some indices, having badly-written queries, etc. We are using MySQL. I can already see the way we query by name of genres instead of some kind of genre id that the DB is a mess. I am trying to do an explain query to figure out why this query is the biggest offender in terms of run time.

```
EXPLAIN 
 SELECT COUNT(v.id) cnt
   FROM non_detail_video_views vv
   JOIN video v
     ON vv.video_id = v.id
   JOIN video_sub_category c
     ON v.video_sub_category_id = c.id
  WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(vv.created_date)) = '2014-06-25'
    AND c.sub_category_name IN ('Rap','R&B','Country','Pop','Metal','Rock'
                               ,'EDM','Christian','Alternative','Jazz','Blues'
                               ,'Reggae','Classical','Folk','Trance') 
  GROUP 
     BY vv.video_id
  ORDER 
     BY vv.created_date DESC;
```

I asked the guy with the direct access to the DB to run the query and he gave me a screenshot back:

[image: query]

This is the non_detail_video_views table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `non_detail_video_views` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sharer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_newgame` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `frompage` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `video_id` (`video_id`),
  KEY `created_date` (`created_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Video table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `referral_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `video_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `video_description` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `video_url` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `video_html` varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
  `video_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `video_sub_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `video_thump` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `payment_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `in_contest` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `repeater` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `coupon_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `noofshares` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `besides` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `facebookpage` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `custom_message` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `custom_link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `video_country_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ages` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gender` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `subscribers` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pay_per_view` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `total_payment` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `pending_amount` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `second_payment` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `welcome_mail` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `add_budget_mail` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `auto_mid_way` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `out_of_budget` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `out_of_budget_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `out_of_budget_3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_refunded` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `refund_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_banned` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `video_id` (`video_url`(767)),
  KEY `created_date` (`created_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

video_sub_category table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video_sub_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `genre_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I haven't done this before, how do I interpret the output?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with querying by genre as opposed to genre_id. When seeking assistance with this kind of problem (if it is a problem), it'd often helpful to provide CREATE statements for each of the relevant tables.

Comment: Not exactly what you have asked for, but this part `WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(vv.created_date)) = '2014-06-25'` could be a reason why it is so slow, because even if there is an index on `created_date`, it will not be used because of the functions.

Comment: I'm sceptical that @ammoQ's suggestion will help performance much but you could try replacing that with `vv.created_date BETWEEN 1403650800 AND 1403737199`

Comment: @Strawberry: It all depends on the size of the table and whether or not there is an appropriate index. See http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/dates

Comment: @Strawberry the schema I got to replicate this table locally is missing some indices. Of course, it doesn't prevent me from working on the back-end code, but it prevents me from seeing which indices exist in production. I do know that the id fields are the primary keys for those tables. video_sub_category_id is not a key and it's not very unique (there's only half a dozen categories)

Comment: Without that information, we're poking around in the dark. That said, there are some people here who are really good at that.

Comment: @Strawberry, good point, I was afraid of that. I'll try to get the necessary information to make my question better.

Comment: @Strawberry I found where the fresher schema is and updated the question

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can suggest is as follows. Rather than doing all the steps and then trying your query, I suggest you try the first step, then the query, then the second step, then the query, etc. Not very scientific I know, but that's how I roll...

1. Change the date comparison to `WHERE vv.created_date BETWEEN 1403650800 AND 1403737199`
2. Remove the existing indexes on vv.video_id and vv.created_date and instead create a compound index on these columns.
3. Add an index on v.video_sub_category_id
4. Add an index on c.sub_category_name